# jquery targeting individual generated list tags

Tags: jquery, css, list, tags, unique-id

I am creating a grocery list where items can be added, deleted, and crossed off. My problem right now involves crossing items off and being able to undo it. Clicking on the item (the text), will cross it off and double clicking the item will uncross it.Unfortunately, every "li" tag(with class="food") generated when an item is added to the list will be crossed off when clicked.

```
      $(".food").on({
            click: function(){
              $(this).parent().css("text-decoration","line-through"); 
            },
            dblclick: function(){
              $(this).parent().css("text-decoration", "none"); 
            }
        });
```

I understand why every item is being targeted. My issue is either finding a way to generate a unique id when every "li" tag is generated, and then code a way to target them individually or some other solution. I'd like some help figuring this out! Links appreciated.

Comment: adding your html relatedto the script would narrow down the problem

Comment: If the li has the class food then you should delete .parent() from both functions and it might work. If you could provide us the html would help much more.

Comment: Try this : https://jsfiddle.net/nL04cuvy/1/

Comment: Please do provide your related html so we can help you further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `.parent()` and you are done

```js
$(".food").on({
  click: function() {
    $(this).css("text-decoration", "line-through");
  },
  dblclick: function() {
    $(this).css("text-decoration", "none");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="food">apple</li>
  <li class="food">mango</li>
  <li class="food">orange</li>
  <li class="food">banana</li>
  <li class="food">black current</li>
</ul>
```